# Forms based Authentication using AD Account and then redirect to another web site to authenticate

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a web site which is using Windows integrated Login (SSO), so that users don't need to type any user name and password, but when they aren't using their domain accounts to login the computer, the web site will prompt a login box.

I just make a web site with form based login and then it will redirect to above web site. I can login using the AD domain account but after redirect to above web site, it also will prompt login box. How can I bring the credential to above web site?

Many thanks.

Comment: Cookie or Session state can help?

Comment: Are your two sites on the same domain? You generally can't mix built in authentication methods between sites.

Comment: You mean the URL? Yes.
for the redirected web site, it is set to Windows integrated Auth.so is it possible to bring forms login to redirected web site?

Comment: No - you can choose to set a cookie in the Windows Auth app and then uses that in the Forms app I think, but not the other way round